# Externally linked object API info

Tags: python, linked-data

Assume I have an external .blend file \\ourserver\ourshare\ourasset.blend,  with a collection "ourData" representing what we'd like to import into another .blend file, "ourshot.blend".  ourshot.blend has an empty toplevel collection called "Assets" where our linked imports will go.  I can do something like this in Python to reproduce the File->Link... operation:

```
filename = r"\\ourserver\ourshare\ourasset.blend\Collection\ourData"
alc = next((lc for lc in bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children if lc.name=="Assets"), bpy.context.scene.collection)  # wants layer_collection, not Collection type?
bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection = alc  # so is active collection for link()
bpy.ops.wm.link(filename=filename)
```

This produces an "Assets/ourData" entry in the Outliner, with another "ourData" entry contained in that, as would the manual File->Link. I can grab the newly linked thing:

```
ac =  bpy.data.collections['Assets']  # started out empty
obj = ac.objects[0]    # the thing just linked in is only one, since it was empty
print(type(obj))    # bpy.types.Object
```

But I can't seem to figure out where to get interesting link information from "obj".  I'd like to determine the path to the original file it was linked in from, for instance, and I'm not sure the proper way to determine that it is a link, for instance.  There also doesn't seem to be anything that represents the second-level "ourData" Outliner entry?

Comment: Based on what you already have as script you should be able to use `obj.data.library.filepath` to display a relative filepath between current file and import location.

Comment: To determine if it is liked data instead of an object created in the open file you should be able to use `obj.data.is_library_indirect`

Comment: Unfortunately, after retrieving "obj" as shown above, obj.data is None.
obj.name is "ourData" as expected  and obj can be retrieved via bpy.data.objects['ourData'] as well.  type(obj) is "bpy.types.Object", and obj.type is "EMPTY".  

I'm a software type, not a DCC artist, and I don't really know my way around Blender, but FWIW I haven't found anything in the Outliner UI or elsewhere that seems to display the linkage filename either.

Comment: in the outliner there is a drop down selection for the type of data displayed. You can select blend file as the data type to display linked file data. You will then want to collapse the "Current File" tree to easily see linked file information.

Comment: That "Blender File" view is showing entries from the bpy.data.libraries collection, of class bpy.Types.Library, not attributes of the collection item that I refer to as "obj".  I still can't see how to programmatically find that library entry given "obj", the object from the scene collection.  obj.library would seem to be where this should be, and thus obj.library.filepath, but obj.library is None as well.